# new[] expression does not respect alignment in Microsoft VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

If new[] expression is used to create an array of objects having destructors,
the objects in the array may not be properly alligned

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma pack(8)
struct A{
  int64_t i;
  char dummy;
  ~A(){}
};

int main(){
  A* pa= new A[2];
  printf("sizeof(A)= %d, pointer= %p", sizeof(A), pa);
}
```

(I build 32-bit target with VC++ 2010 express)

The output (on my computer) is:

```
 sizeof(A)= 16 pointer= 00344f4c
```

(sizeof(A)= 16 shows that compiler undrstand the alignment requirements for A and the struct is padded with 7 bytes **[ edited: __alignof(A) also returns 8 ]**)

I understand why it happens: new[] needs to store array length and it use for this purpose first 4 bytes of allocated memory, then it allocates the array itself without proper padding.

From a practical viewpoint such a behaviour is definitely poor, 
but is it standard compliant or not?

Comment: That's unbelievable. Even our in-house custom implementation of `operator new` respects alignment.

Comment: isn't this the result of your `#pragma pack(8)` still in effect in your main ?

Comment: @sharptooth custom operator new simply allocates memory which is used by compiler to generate code for new expression. Allocated memory is always properly aligned, but objects are placed by compiler to wrong place inside this memory

Comment: @Adrien Plisson sizof(A)==16 shows that pragma pack take effect

Comment: Th standard grantees alignment of the returned result. I doubt that Visual Studio is broken. So your hypothesis must be incorrect. I don't understand why you think it is not aligned.

Comment: @user396672: Yes, I understand that. I just couldn't expect VC++ can ignore alignment requirements.

Comment: @sharptooth: The Standard only requires the alignment to be for any type the user can declare. On x86, the user can only declare types that require 4byte alignment, and doesn't need any other alignment, if the user stays within Standard C++. VS is not obliged to provide any functionality for leaving that region of code. Of course, since they do, it's not unreasonable to expect that such tools work.

Comment: @DeadMG: Doesn't 8-byte int require 8-byte alignment?

Comment: @sharptooth: VS is not obliged to provide it, so it falls under extensions like SSE types. Of course, in C++0x it will be mandated to provide a 64bit integral type, but as of right now, it isn't.

Comment: @DeadMG: I see now. Thank you. I learned something here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `__declspec` for this purpose. Your code generated misaligned objects on my computer too (using VS2010) but when I changed to `__declspec(align(8))`, the pointers were correctly aligned.

I believe that `pragma pack` only changes the *size* of the struct and doesn't make any guarantees about it's location.

Comment: This worked for me too. Strangely, `__alignof(A)` gave 8 even without the `__declspec`.

Comment: yes - if i understand http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65%28v=vs.80%29.aspx correctly, the #pragma pack effects only the alignment inside the struct (e.g. the relative offset of each member to each other). __declspec(align(8)) does both, which is what you want.

Comment: Indeed, it works! But why pragma and project settings have no effect?

Comment: @user396672: If my answer solved your problem, mark it as accepted. `pragma pack` only affects the *packing* of the struct, i.e., only aligns the size of the struct, not it's memory locations.

Comment: @ DeadMG I've marked :) it seems also that /ZpX project setting simply defaults implicit pragma value, and doesn't affect code generation and runtime

Answer (score 3):

The standard guarantees that the memory is correctly aligned.

I doubt that Visual Studio got something so basic wrong.

Currently I don't follow why you think it is not aligned?

Are you trying to suggest it should be aligned to 16 byte boundaries?
That is not required by the standard. It may only need to align to 4 byte boundaries.

#### 3.11 Alignment [basic.align]

> 2 A fundamental alignment is represented by an alignment less than or equal to the greatest alignment supported by the implementation in all contexts, which is equal to alignof(std::max_align_t) (18.2).

Thus the following code should print out the maximum required alignment of the implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdalign>

int main()
{
        std::cout << alignof(std::max_align_t) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: The `struct` in the question contains a 64-bit member variable, so the address should be 8-bytes aligned.

Comment: It must be aligned to 8 byte boundary. MS compiler adds 7-byte padding to the struct, therefore, it understands 8-byte requirement imposed by member type, #pragma pack (and default alignment too)

Comment: @sharptooth: @user396672: That is **not** a requirement of the standard.

Comment: @Martin York: That's strange. Why does our custom allocator ensure 8-bytes alignment then...

Comment: @sharptooth: No idea, but on x86, if you're not allocating SSE types, you don't need 8byte alignment. Of course, if you're working with some other low-level technology like CUDA you may need more alignment, and if you want relatively easy porting to x64, 8byte alignment isn't a bad idea.

Comment: @Martin York #include <cstdalign> - No such file.. :) http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/524342/implement-std-max-align-t-in-visual-c

Comment: @ user396672: I am using the spec n3225 your compiler may not support taht yet.

Comment: @Martin York definitely not supported. However, I've tried __aligneof(A) and I've got 8. If it is a fundamental alignment for A (?), then max system alignment can not be less then 8.

Comment: @user396672: What do you base that assertion on (max alignment can not be less than 8)? I have no idea myself but you seem to be getting the number from a lot of assumptions. Do you have any anything you are basing this off?  I have no idea what __aligneof() does that is some MS thing.

Comment: @ Martin: I only suppose that MS __alignof() is a MS replacement for standard alignof. If so, then the compiler violates the standard. If no, you are right, it is impossible to say anything as there are no direct way to check fundamental alignment for the structure (there are only some indirect suggestions). But this impossibility is not a good thing itself.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting.  My first question would be: what happens without the #pragma pack?  What is the native alignement for this struct.  The operator new has no means of knowing what options you might have set with the pragma, so its presence or absense has no effect here.  And formally, there's no violation of the standard, since Intel doesn't *require* any alignment for anything (but maintaining proper alignment sure helps performance).  All in all, it doesn't seem like a desirable "feature", but it's a QoI issue, and not a standard conformance one.

Comment: without pragma there is exactly the same result. Project default alignment is 8, __alignof(A) returns 8. If  __alignof(A) actually returns the alignment of A (otherwise, what it returns?) then new must return properly aligned pointer, but it doesn't. But formally speaking, ms-specific __align may return anything :). I suppose, it was a bug that MS doesn't fix due to compatability problems. Perhaps, some placement new[] invokations in old applications may not reserve enough extra space. And they have fixed the bug by introducing special declspec, not by default (it is only my hypothesis)

Answer (score 1):

Well to answer your question literally I don't think the standard says anything about #pragma pack at all. So I would say that your code has undefined behavour according to the standard.

Comment: I also tried __alignof(A), it returns 8. If we can treat MS's __alignof as replacement for standard alignof(A), then  fundamental alignment for type A is 8 and must be respected by compiler

Answer (score 0):

```
 printf("sizeof(A)= %d, pointer= %08x", sizeof(A), pa);
```

As a token of caution, use `%p` when you want to print *memory address*:

```
printf("sizeof(A)= %d, pointer= %p", sizeof(A), pa);
```

`%x` expects `unsigned int` whose size may be different from the size of a pointer.

Comment: ... and %zu for size_t values.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC the default packing is on byte alignment, use [/Zpn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh3e3fd0%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to set to another packing, then you get your padding. (or #pragma pack(n) )

EDIT: come to think about I think the default packing even varies between VS versions

Comment: default packing in project settings is also 8 bytes /Zp8

Answer (score 0):

If `struct A` just contains [plain old data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure), you can use `aligned_malloc` (see [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z34s9c6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)). If it needs to be constructed, you can combine this with the `placement new` operator. Something like this (I don't have Microsoft VC++, so it might not compile):

```
void* buf = _aligned_malloc (2 * sizeof (struct A), 8) ;
A* pa = new (buf) A[2];
```

Deleting this is a pain: you have to call pa[i].~A() explicitly for each array element, and then `_aligned_free (buf)`.

Answer (score 0):

`operator new()` which keyword `new` calls under the hood, has no knowledge of type's alignment. The only alignment requirement is that `operator new()` has to allocate memory suitably aligned for a built-in type with the largest alignment requirement, which is often 8 on a 32-bit platform (the alignment requirement of double).

Having said that, the example you posted allocates memory aligned on 8-byte boundary as it should.

Comment: Have you actually read the question? It is about result of new[] expression, not about implementation of new[] operator (i.e.memory allocator) which (you are right) works properly.